# Firestore Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am new here and reporting a issue face few days

> Enabling Cloud Firestore will prevent you from using Cloud Datastore with this project, notably from the associated App Engine app

All solutions I found online are completely targeting experts/individual who knows their way around Firebase and Google Cloud. To me, this error is a roadblock. I tried using my other Gmail accounts, creating new projects and the same error appears. even the cancel and close buttons seen are not working I have to refresh just to get back.

Kindly help or guide me what should I do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a project where you try to enable Firesore has Datastore enabled already and they can not live together.
What to do depends on what you want to achieve. If Datastore database is not valuable for you, you can just delete it and then it should be possible to enable Firestore.

Answer (score -1):

you used Incognito. this problem is solved